# How to exchange numbers in string?

Tags: php

can you please help me with finding right function for exchanging numbers in string? Numbers are separated with ":".

For example

```
"2:0" to "0:2"
"101:50" to "50:101"
```

Thank you.

Comment: We will be glad to help if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [ask] a good question and [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Start by looking up [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in the PHP Manual

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, you can try the any of the ways here.

```
<?php
//using regex
$re = '/(\d+):(\d+)/i';
$str = '50:101';
$subst = '$2:$1';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo "The string $str after exchange is ".$result;

echo PHP_EOL;
// concatenating parts after explode
$parts = explode(':',$str);
echo "The string $str after exchange is $parts[1]:$parts[0]";

echo PHP_EOL;
//using explode, array_reverse and implode
$str = '50:101';
$result = implode(':', array_reverse(explode(':',$str)));
echo "The string $str after exchange is ".$result;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/OkY18

Comment: Best not to lecture others when posting answers. That could have easily been a (much less confronting) comment. Note that I've edited and removed said lecturing.  And a bit ironic that you are a seasoned veteran here, yet 1) post such a comment in bold text (not very nice, especially given the updated Code of Conduct), and 2) answer an off-topic question (being very broad).

Answer (score 0):

Simply `explode()` the string and then reform it.

```
$str = '100:200';
$bits = explode(':',$str);
echo $bits[1] . ':' . $bits[0];
```

RESULT

```
200:100
```